# Como introducir datos en la misma linea

Tags: java, scanner, entrada

Como puedo introducir datos en la misma linea?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce la hora");

    int hora = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(":");
    int minutos = sc.nextInt();

    sc.close();
}
```

Ejemplo salida

```
Introduce la hora
22
:50
```

Yo quisiera que al introducir los datos me saliese en la misma linea, 22:50

He probado con string y nextLine() pero tampoco.

Comment: El salto de línea viene por el propio usuario que introduce los datos. Pero la cuestión es porqué quieres hacerlo de esta forma, es impráctica y liosa. O bien le dices al usuario que introduzca la hora en una línea incluyendo el `:` (para eso es una notación estándar) y lo parseas tú, o bien después de la hora imprimes "Introduce los minutos". En el primer caso, siempre es útil especificar el formato ("Introduce la hora (hh:mm)") para que la gente no te ponga información inesperada (por ejemplo, segundos `22:50:00`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es introducir datos en la misma linea lo que tienes que hacer es usar `print` no `println` que de dara un salto de linea cuando te presente el mensaje te quedaria asi tu codigo,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Introduce la hora");

    int hora = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(":");
    int minutos = sc.nextInt();

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Creo que el OP se refiere al salto de línea entre el `22` y el `:`.

Comment: Si me dices que es el : 50 hay si estariamos de acuerdo en dado caso lo que tendria que hacer es pedir los valores por JOPtionPane y luego imprimir el resultado de las variable

Answer (score 2):

Si no necesitas manejarlas más adelante, solo que salgan en pantalla prueba con Strings de esta manera.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce la hora (HH:MM)");

        String horacompleta=sc.nextLine();
        String minutos=horacompleta.substring(3);
        String hora=horacompleta.substring(0, 2);
        System.out.print(hora+":"+minutos);

        sc.close();
    }
```

Resultado:

```
Introduce la hora (HH:MM)
12:40
12:40
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión lo más fácil es indicarle al usuario el formato con el cual debe ingresar la hora

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce la hora (HH:MM) ");

    string horaCompleta = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(horaCompleta);

    sc.close();
}
```

Si después necesitas tener los datos de la hora y los minutos tenés 2 opciones:

1- Como le dijiste al usuario que ingrese la hora en formato HH:MM y lo guardas en un string, podés obtener los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
int hora = Integer.parseInt(horaCompleta.substring(0, 2));
int minutos = Integer.parseInt(horaCompleta.substring(3));
```

Con eso ya tendrías ambos datos en formato `int` y lo podés usar de la forma que necesites.

2- La otra opción es pedirle que ingrese 2 datos en lugar de uno:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce la hora ");
    int hora = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduce los minutos ");
    int minutos = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(hora + ":" + minutos);

    sc.close();
}
```

De esta forma tenes los 2 datos por separado y te los muestra en el formato convencional 22:50.

Espero te sea de ayuda!